# filtering words from text with exploits

Tags: php, regex

I have filter which filters bad words like 'ass' 'fuck' etc. Now I am trying to handle exploits like "f*ck", "sh/t".

One thing I could do is matching each words with dictionary of bad word having such exploits. But this is pretty static and not good approach.

Another thing I can do is, using levenshtein distance. Words with levenshtein distance = 1 should be blocked. But this approach also prone to give false positive.

```
if(!ctype_alpha($text)&& levenshtein('shit', $text)===1)
{
//match
}
```

I am looking for some way of using regex. May be I can combine levenshtein distance with `regex`, but I could not figure it out.

Any suggestion is highly appreciable.

Comment: So you want to filter out words that are already censored?

Comment: [Scunthorpe problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem)

Comment: I second @AmalMurali's link, but this may get you started (it definitely has flaws, that's why it is a quick comment): [`[s*/][h*/][i*/][t*/]`](http://regex101.com/r/wA6vB3)

Comment: Sam: I dont have only one such words, lots of. need better generalized approach

Comment: 'fukk' is obviously exploited, but 'shot' is a valid and completely different word than 'shit'. Besides, 'ass' also means 'donkey' (*Equus africanus asinus*). What I'm trying to say is that you will never get this right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like stated in the comments, it is hard to get this right. This snippet, far from perfect, will check for matches where letters are substituted for the same number of other characters.

It may give you a general idea of how you could solve this, although much more logic is needed if you want to make it smarter. This filter, for instance will not filter 'fukk', 'f ck', 'f**ck', 'fck', '.fuck' (with leading dot) or 'fück', while it does probably filter out '++++' to replace it with 'beep'. But it also filters 'f*ck', 'f**k', 'f*cking' and 'sh1t', so it could do worse. :)

An easy way to make it better, is to split the string in a smarter way, so punctuation marks aren't glued to the word they are adjacent to. Another improvement could be to remove all non-alphabetic characters from each word, and check if the remaining letters are in the same order in a word. That way, 'f\/ck' would also match 'fuck'. Anyway, let your imagination run wild, but be careful for false positives. And trust me that 'they' will always find a way to express themselves in a way that bypasses your filter.

```
<?php 
$badwords = array('shit', 'fuck');
$text = 'Man, I shot this f*ck, sh/t! fucking fucker sh!t fukk. I love this. ;)';
$words = explode(' ', $text);

// Loop through all words.
foreach ($words as $word)
{
  $naughty = false;
  // Match each bad word against each word.
  foreach ($badwords as $badword)
  {
    // If the word is shorter than the bad word, it's okay. 
    // It may be bigger. I've done this mainly, because in the example given, 
    // 'f*ck,' will contain the trailing comma. This could be easily solved by
    // splitting the string a bit smarter. But the added benefit, is that it also
    // matches derivatives, like 'f*cking' or 'f*cker', although that could also 
    // result in more false positives.
    if (strlen($word) >= strlen($badword))
    {
      $wordOk = false;
      // Check each character in the string.
      for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($badword); $i++)
      {
        // If the letters don't match, and the letter is an actual 
        // letter, this is not a bad word.
        if ($badword[$i] !== $word[$i] && ctype_alpha($word[$i]))
        {
          $wordOk = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      // If the word is not okay, break the loop.
      if (!$wordOk)
      {
        $naughty = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  // Echo the sensored word.
  echo $naughty ? 'beep ' : ($word . ' ');
}
```

Comment: thanks dude, yes they will always bypass filter : )
Here is above code I compiled http://ideone.com/9kaksF why it does not give any result

Comment: You moved the echo to outside the last `}`.

Comment: thanks, is there any way to put `*` of same length of sensored word rather then `beep`?