# Bad words filter

Tags: php, replace

Im trying to do a bad words filter with the following function:

```
function sacarmalaspalabras($texto) {
$palabras = Array(" sexo "," concha ", " pete "," vagina ", " culo ", " anal ", " puta ", " puto    ", " putas ", " putos ", " preservativo ", " preservativos ", " orgasmo ",  " porno ", " pija ", " teta " , " tetas ", " condon ", " masturbar ", " masturbaba ", " poronga ", " concha ", " hentai ", " gay ", " lesbiana ", " orto ", " choto ", " chota ", " marica " ," maricon ", " semen ", " garchar ", "hentai","porn"," porn " );

 $palabrasnew = Array(" s*xo "," c*ncha ", " p*te ", " v*gina ", " cul* ", "an*l ", " p*ta ", " p*to ", " p*tas ", " p*tos ", " preservativ* ", " preservativ*s ", " or**smo ", " p*rno ", " pij* ", " tet* ", " tet*s ", " cond*n ", " mastur*** ", " mast**baba ", " poron** ", " conch* " , " h**tai ", " g*y ", " lesb**na ", " ort* ", " chot* ", " chot* ", " maric* ", " maric*n ", " sem*n ", " garch** ", "h**tai", "p*rn", " p*rn " );

$texto = str_replace($palabras,$palabrasnew,$texto);

return $texto;
}
```

the problem is that its replacing the word only if its between white spaces lets say i want to filter the word "ass" , if someone says: "that ass, another thing" it will not replace it due to the comma. But also i want to prevent the replacement of words inside other words, lets say im trying to filter the word "sex" but i dont want to filter "sexuality".

how can i use a wildcard on str_replace? so its something like %ass% there might be some words that will fall in the filter, but it will be the minority.

Comment: Why do your arrays contain spaces in the first place?

Comment: i guess he want so be sure its a new word :)

Comment: when has medical terms a bad word

Comment: porn is not a bad word...and it's in your array twice.

Comment: Here, see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/23791792/ - the [**accepted answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23792559/) works very well.

Comment: Relevant: [Obscenity Filters: Bad Idea, or Incredibly Intercoursing Bad Idea?](http://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was just going to suggest that link. The answer that guy gave is brilliant! ;-) Kidding of course. It will probably filter `sexuality`.

Comment: @GolezTrol I do agree ;) Great work +1 on both counts. I keep it handy for such an occasion.

Comment: Ed Heal tell google adsense why medical terms are bad words, i dont understand it either

Comment: Haha. Buttociated press =3. That link is priceless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the function using preg_replace instead

```
function sacarmalaspalabras($texto) {
$palabras = Array("/\bsexo\b/i", "/\bconcha\b/i", "/\bpete\b/i", "/\bvagina\b/i", "/\bculo\b/i", "/\banal\b/i", "/\bputa\b/i", "/\bputo\b/i", "/\bputas\b/i", "/\bputos\b/i", "/\bpreservativo\b/i", "/\bpreservativos\b/i", "/\borgasmo\b/i", "/\bporno\b/i", "/\bpija\b/i", "/\bteta\b/i", "/\btetas\b/i", "/\bcondon\b/i", "/\bmasturbar\b/i", "/\bmasturbaba\b/i", "/\bporonga\b/i", "/\bconcha\b/i", "/\bhentai\b/i", "/\bgay\b/i", "/\blesbiana\b/i", "/\borto\b/i", "/\bchoto\b/i", "/\bchota\b/i", "/\bmarica\b/i", "/\bmaricon\b/i", "/\bsemen\b/i", "/\bgarchar\b/i", "/\bhentai\b/i", "/\bporn\b/i", "/\bporn\b/i");

  $palabrasnew = Array("s*xo", "c*ncha", "p*te", "v*gina", "cul*", "an*l", "p*ta", "p*to", "p*tas", "p*tos", "preservativ*", "preservativ*s", "or**smo", "p*rno", "pij*", "tet*", "tet*s", "cond*n", "mastur***", "mast**baba", "poron**", "conch*", "h**tai", "g*y", "lesb**na", "ort*", "chot*", "chot*", "maric*", "maric*n", "sem*n", "garch**", "h**tai", "p*rn", "p*rn");

  $texto = preg_replace($palabras,$palabrasnew,$texto);

  return $texto;
}
```

You can test it by running a line like this:

```
echo sacarmalaspalabras("Sexologist sexo sexu osex");
```

The output is : Sexologist s*xo sexu osex

Comment: excelent! thanks a lot, is there a way of making it case insensitive so that it detects for example SEX

Comment: @gabrielmellace Good point! It's already case insensitive - that's what the "i" after the "/" means in "/\bsexo\b/i"

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `str_replace`, you can use `preg_replace` and surround each of your *malas palabras* with word boundaries `\b`. Change your `$palabras` array to `"/\bsexo\b/"`, `"/\bconcha\b/"` etc. and use `$texto = preg_replace($palabras, $palabrasnew, $texto);`. This will only replace the exact words, rather than matches within a word.

That said (and as others have mentioned), obscenity filters are notoriously difficult (impossible?) to implement properly, so you may be wasting your time...

Comment: thanks! its true it might be dificult, but in spanish there are less colissions that in english!

Answer (score 1):

I'll preface this with saying that I dont' know PHP, but it looks like you might be able to try http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php and use a regular expression to implement your wildcards.

That said, I've seen some pretty poorly implemented "foul language filters" and they tend to be something like this.

More words than you might think will get triggered. Off the top of my head... Assembly, brass, stitch (my own screen name has been blocked because of "tit" :p )

So if it's something a lot of people will be seeing, you may want to try for something more robust.